# Firestore rules: unable to verify role in subcollection

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm having difficulties to setting up my security rules

Data Structure

```
-- books (collection)
   -- bookId (autogenerated Id - doc) 
      -- {chapter: text}, {chapter: text}, 

userBooks
   -- email (email of user logged in - doc)
      -- books (sub collection)
        -- bookId (referencing bookId doc on collection book)
           -- role: admin or read
```

The use case is as follow, a user with admin role is the only one permitted to share a book, allowing him to add an entry in books of another user.

created the function trying to achieve that but it does not pass successfully

I'm am logged in as user with email **userWantsToShare@gmail.com**. When user tries to share his book to **addUser@gmail.com** I make the following request:

userWantsToShare@gmail.com making the request to write under addUser@gmail.com collection.

```
final role = {'role': 'edit'};
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('userBooks')
        .doc("addUser@gmail.com")
        .collection('books')
        .doc('9KHYZJVBY3BNAlYPYYoA')
        .set(role);
```

When coming to firebase

this should translate to /userBooks/addUser@gmail.com/books/9KHYZJVBY3BNAlYPYYoA
Data  {'role': 'edit'}.

```
match /userBooks/{emailId}/books/{bookId} {
      allow write: if isSharedEmail(bookId);
}

//here im verifying the user that wants to share has admin role and therefore is authorised to write in another user book subcollection
function isSharedEmail(bookId){
//this should translate to /userBooks/userWantToShare@gmail.com/books/9KHYZJVBY3BNAlYPYYoA
   get(/databases/$(database)/documents/userBooks/$(request.auth.token.email)/books/$(bookId)).data.role == "admin" ;
}
```

As userWantToShare@gmail.com has under that path admin role it should allow the insertion. But most likely I'm omitting something as it does not work at all.

What m I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, for anyone making the same dumb mistake as I did. When making the call to the function isSharedEmail was outside the context.

Meaning that by moving the function to the scope inside the context was enough to make it work

Before: not working

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /userBooks/{email} {
      allow write: if ( isAppShared())
      allow read: if true;
    }
  } 
}
  
function isAppShared() {
  return  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/userBooks/$(request.auth.token.email)).data.bookId == request.resource.data.bookId; 
}
```

After: Working

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /userBooks/{email} {
      allow write: if ( isAppShared())
      allow read: if true;
    }
    
    function isAppShared() {
      return  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/userBooks/$(request.auth.token.email)).data.bookId == request.resource.data.bookId; 
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hey there, would you mind accepting your own answer so that this question appears as solved? That way anyone with the same issue will be able to see this question and see that a solution has been found